# How to access the computation result of an Akka Stream?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm attempting to return the result of a stream operation which in this case is:

1. sum a list
2. square the value
3. square the value

which is represented as:

```
        .fold(0, (aggr, next) -> aggr + next)
        .map(x -> x * x)
        .map(x -> x * x)
```

To access the value I use

```
final AtomicInteger returnValue = new AtomicInteger();
```

followed by :

```
        .to(Sink.foreach(x -> {
            returnValue.set(x);
            System.out.println("got: " + x);
        }))
```

Which requires a blocking call to allow the stream to complete which is not acceptable:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

If I use:

```
    CompletableFuture<Object> futureValue =
            ask(actorRef, Done.done(), Duration.ofMillis(5000)).toCompletableFuture();
    System.out.println(futureValue.toCompletableFuture().get().toString());
```

an error is returned :

```
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://StreamsExamples/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/$$a-actorRefSource#1663100910]] after [5000 ms]. Message of type [akka.Done$]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
```

The recipient actor in this case is Source and returns the following on a `Done.done` message:

```
return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
```

Can an Akka stream be used to return the computed value from the stream? The only alternative is to store the computed value in a DB or send it to a Kafka topic when the value is computed in :

```
.to(Sink.foreach(x -> {
```

?

Complete src:

```
import akka.Done;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.stream.CompletionStrategy;
import akka.stream.OverflowStrategy;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class GetStreamValue {

    final static akka.actor.ActorSystem system = akka.actor.ActorSystem.create("StreamsExamples");

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {


        int bufferSize = 100;
        final Source<Integer, ActorRef> source =
                Source.actorRef(
                        elem -> {
                            // complete stream immediately if we send it Done
                            if (elem == Done.done()) {
                                return Optional.of(CompletionStrategy.immediately());
                            }
                            else {
                                return Optional.empty();
                            }
                        },
                        // never fail the stream because of a message
                        elem -> Optional.empty(),
                        bufferSize,
                        OverflowStrategy.dropHead());

        final AtomicInteger returnValue = new AtomicInteger();

        final ActorRef actorRef = source
                .fold(0, (aggr, next) -> aggr + next)
                .map(x -> x * x)
                .map(x -> x * x)
                .to(Sink.foreach(x -> {
                    returnValue.set(x);
                    System.out.println("got: " + x);
                }))
                .run(system);

        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).forEach(i -> actorRef.tell(i, ActorRef.noSender()));
        Arrays.asList(1,2).forEach(i -> actorRef.tell(i, ActorRef.noSender()));
        actorRef.tell(Done.done(), ActorRef.noSender());

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println("returnValue is "+returnValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be missing is to understand the concept of **materialized value** in Akka Streams. Scan through [this part](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#stream-materialization) of the documentation especially around combining materialized values. I also had a go at trying to explain this concept [here](http://voee.tech/blog/akka-streams-rxjava2-project-reactor-api-comparison) (search for *Materialized value*). If you grok materialized value, then perhaps what I write here will make more sense.

A call to `Source.actorRef(..)` returns `Source<T, ActorRef>` where T is data type of elements flowing through the stream (in your case it's `Integer`) and `ActorRef` is the **materialized value** of that `Source`. You get the materialized value synchronously when you call `run`  on `RunnableGraph` which is what `to(...)` call returns.

That `ActorRef` is how you can "drive" the stream as per `Source.actorRef(...)` semantics.

Now the question is how you get your hands on the data that passes through the stream. In your case you're reducing all `Integers` into one, so instead of using `Sink.foreach(...)` which is good for side effects, you can use [Sink.head](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/head.html). You see,`Sink`s can also produce **materialized values** and in case of `Sink.head` it materializes to `CompletionStage` of the first element in the stream, which in your case is the only element. So let's try that:

```java
final ActorRef actorRef = source
                                .fold(0, (aggr, next) -> aggr + next)
                                .map(x -> x * x)
                                .map(x -> x * x)
                                .to(Sink.head())
                                .run(system);
```

Ok, that didn't help too much. You still are getting just the materialized value of the `Source`. To get the materialized value of the `Sink` we need to explicitly ask for it:

```java
final Pair<ActorRef, CompletionStage<Integer>> matVals =
      source
        .fold(0, (aggr, next) -> aggr + next)
        .map(x -> x * x)
        .map(x -> x * x)
        .toMat(Sink.head(), Keep.both())
        .run(system);
```

Now we get both `Source` and `Sink` materialized values. You can drive your stream via the `ActorRef` as before:

```java
final ActorRef actorRef = matVals.first();

Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).forEach(i -> actorRef.tell(i, ActorRef.noSender()));
Arrays.asList(1,2).forEach(i -> actorRef.tell(i, ActorRef.noSender()));
actorRef.tell(Done.done(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

and also you can use `CompletableStage` API to get your value out of the stream. Like say this:

```java
Integer folded = matVals.second().toCompletableFuture().join();
```

Yes, this is blocking, but you need somehow to stop the main thread from finishing before the streams runs to completion.

Comment: thanks, does using Keep.both() mean 'we get both Source and Sink materialized values' ?

Comment: to get the value can also use : CompletionStage<Integer> future  = matVals.second();
        final Integer folded = future.toCompletableFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Yes, using Keep.both() means exactly that

Comment: future.toCompletableFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) will work too. It's still blocking, though with timeout.